# How to import multiple .vcf file programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

I have multiple vcf files in my sdcard. I want import those vcf files into my contacts.

I am using the below code :

```
File file = new File(storage_path);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/x-vcard");
        startActivity(intent);
```

By using above code i can unable to import one vcf file at a time. I want to import multiple vcf files at a time. By using above code i am getting duplicate contacts also.

Is there any other efficient way to import contacts except intent ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Intent.ACTION_PICK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK) instead of Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Answer (score 0):

Android has nothing built-in for vCard import, in terms of a traditional Java API. There is this [third-party library](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard-android) and perhaps others, you can Use This Library to impliment any requirement